# Executing Java Jar file from PHP

Tags: java, php, exec

Do not slaugther me as there are multiple threads on this topic which I of course have found when searching for an answer. Nevertheless, my problem seems to be different as I do not get any response on the exec() call at all. Here is some information:

- I am on MacOS running PHP 5.4.7 on Apache 2.2.22 and try to run a jar file from Java 1.6.0_35.
- I can execute simple commands as "ls -l", "which java" or "pwd", but any try to call java - even "/usr/bin/java -version" fails without any response; the PHP script just stops discarding any other command after the exec() call
- I do not get any output, neither from the script itself, nor in any error log.
- I tried exec, shell_exec, system in any possible way, not success.
- I made sure every piece of the java call including the binary, the jar file etc. are present, accessible with absolute path; and that, of course, the command runs on the command line without any problem
- The call itself looks like this '/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /Users/twolff/Projects//bin/java/net.adternity.utils.xml2xls/dist/net.adternity.utils.xml2xls.jar --input="/private/tmp/report_rUEsDe.xml" --output="/private/tmp/report_7o1lFb.xls"'.
- I checked the PHP config, but cannot see anything wrong (e.g. disable_functions, safe_mode, etc.)
- I am not running MAMP with the DYLIB environment variable problem

I am lost now, where to continue my investigation and would be glad if anyone can help me out. Here is the code, that I am running in the test script:

```
try {
  $output = "";
  $return_val = 0;
  echo exec('/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /Users/twolff/Projects/<project_name>/bin/java/net.adternity.utils.xml2xls/dist/net.adternity.utils.xml2xls.jar --input="/private/tmp/report_rUEsDe.xml" --output="/private/tmp/report_7o1lFb.xls"', $output, $return_val);
  echo "<br/>";
  echo serialize($output);
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $return_val;
  echo "<br/>";
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  echo "<br/>";
}
echo "DONE";
```

Again, if I just use "which java" (or anything else except for Java itself), I get output like this:

```
/usr/bin/java
a:1:{i:0;s:13:"/usr/bin/java";}
0
DONE
```

Trying to run a Java app does not return ANYTHING, the browser just does nothing. No output, no error log.

Thanks for looking into this.

Tobias.

Comment: Is the path to the jar file right,  -jar /Users/twolff/Projects/<project_name>...  is <project_name> right?

Comment: have you tried wrapping the java command in a shell script?

Comment: Add `2>&1` to see any console errors. Otherwise it's a system configuration thingy, e.g. the webserver user is constrained to not run executables elsewhere.

Comment: is it a permissions thing?  What do you run as when you execute it command line?  PHP might not have the same permissions as root, which is what you're likely running from command line as.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. <project_name> was intentional, sorry for not revealing that piece :-) I will try the shell script as well as the console errors.

Comment: I have tried the script and after fixing error codes 127 (not found) and 126 (not executable), the result is the same. The browser does just nothing. Trying to log any console output, did not work as well - doing 2> /tmp/error.log 1> /tmp/out.log just created to empty files.

Comment: About the permissing - you are right, I am not running this as the webserver user as it has no bash, but I check each and every part of the path to both the java and jar file. I always get something like this "drwxr-xr-x", so it should be fine. And again, the krux is that I do not get any error at all.